# change certain colors of an image on website using php

Tags: php, flash, colors

I'd like to change certain color in an image on a webpage based on user selected color, it this possible using php or javascript.

if it not possible or will be difficult, how do i do it using flash?

please help me with sample code or website.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set parts of the image as transparent and save it in a format that supports transparency. Then put the image inside a `div` and set the `background-color` CSS property of the `div`. This will only allow you to set one colour within the image, however.

Comment: hello, thanks for the tip. i thought of this before, but had troubles implementing it. which image format should i use, gif or png? is there anyway i could change at least two colors?

Comment: I would recommend png, as it was developed to improve upon the gif format. I suppose you could place multiple <div>s behind the image, in different places with different background-colors, but that will get messy fast.